# Is there a flag for documents marked as soft deleted?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a database that is marked to use soft deletions. I am using a tool to migrate the documents from notes into a SQL database, but when it migrates, it migrates the soft deleted documents as regular ones. Is there a field or flag that gets set that is visible to show if a document has been marked for soft deletion?

Comment: Did you try NotesDocument.isDeleted? I am quite sure, that this works for softdeleted documents as well..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a field or flag, but any database with soft deletions should also have a view or folder named "($Trash)", and all soft-deleted documents should be visible in that view or folder.

What you could do is, before migrating documents, iterate through the Trash view/folder and build a list of the document unique ids (UNIDs) it contains. Then, when migrating documents, check each UNID against that list and don't migrate anything in the list.